# Aggregation is not working with the $geoNear

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing something very weird while I'm using the aggregate function with the following pipeline:

```
[
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: [6.0950994999999999, 49.8914114000000026],
      distanceField: 'distance',
    },
  },
]
```

this is what I'm getting while I'm invoking the aggregate function:

> $geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.

I enabled the mongoose debugging mode `mongoose.set('debug', true);`

And this what  I'm getting in the logs

> Mongoose: liveRestaurants.aggregate([ { '$geoNear': { near: [ 6.0950995, 49.8914114 ], distanceField: 'distance' } }], {})

Actually It is at the first timeline.

Any Idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try in this way,

```
[
{
    $geoNear: {
    near: {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [6.0950994999999999, 49.8914114000000026]
    },
    distanceField: 'distance'
    },
},
]
```

Comment: I found this issue I will answer it in a separate thread. Thank you